# Pushing object in an array results to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a method which I am using inside a v-for loop. The method is called in a child div.

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in timesheetRequests">
    <h6 class="card-title mt-3"  :id="'req_'+index" v-if="yearMonthInsertion(item,index)">Something</h6>
       .
       .
       .
</div>
```

And the method is defined below like this

```
  yearMonthInsertion:function(item,index){
     //alert("yearMonthInsertion")
     var meta = item["meta"]
     var last_updated_on  = meta['last_updated_on']
     last_updated_on = last_updated_on.replaceAll("-","/")

     var requestUpdateDate = moment(last_updated_on,"YYYY/MM/DD")

     var month = requestUpdateDate.format("MMMM")
     var day   = requestUpdateDate.format('D');
     var year  = requestUpdateDate.format('YYYY'); 

     console.log("HERE...ll")
     var obj = {}
     obj["month"] = month
     obj["status"] = true

     this.date_element.push(obj)

     console.log("THIS....")
     console.log(this)

  }
```

[image: See the console output here]

When I remove the line,mentioned below, to push object in array then the error goes away . I simply want to add items to the array when the v-for loop is being run

> this.date_element.push(index)

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0):

`v-if` is not the right place to execute this code, because you don't know when and how many times the function will be called. You push into `date_element`, but you never clear it so the array length will only grow.

You should probably define `this.date_element` as a computed property, so it would always be up to date.

Comment: The for loop depends upon the no. of items in this array timesheetRequests so why pushing into a different array results in an infinite loop ?